# ToastAndroid background colour [React-Native]

Tags: react-native, android-toast

I'm using [ToastAndroid](https://reactnative.dev/docs/toastandroid) in my react-native app, and it takes the background colour from the theme of the device by default, but I need to override that. Please don't suggest using some other packages, I know about them. I'm interested if it's somehow possible to do it with this component, imported from 'react-native'. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try changing colors in colors.xml file under android/src/res folders

Comment: What is the attribute name in .xml file

Comment: colorPrimary and colorSecondary you can try them for starters.